# iPhone storyboard how to identify which button is clicked when present modal view controller

Tags: iphone, uibutton, storyboard

I am using storyboard for making iPhone app.
I placed 2 buttons on the main viewcontroller, and add actions to present modal new TestViewController on the Storyboard.
When click 2 buttons, same TestViewController will be shown, but I want to know which button is clicked in the TestViewController viewdidload.
Any advice or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign different segue names to each button and in the prepareForSegue method you can use that information to pass  what you want to the new ViewController.

Answer (score 2):

what @Richard Brown suggested is good.

Assign tag to buttons and use that as below:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ChooseAPlayer"]) {
       TestViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        TestViewController.variablename = buttontag;
    }
}
```